# How can I keep curl output out of mail from my cronjob?

Tags: curl, cron

I have written a Perl script that runs as a daily crontab job that uploads files to Amazon S3 via CURL. I want the output of the cron job emailed to me which works fine but I don't want that email to include messages related to the CURL upload (only those message my script is outputting). Here are the CURL related messages I'm seeing in the daily email right now:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0  230M    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0  230M    0     0    0  544k      0  1519k  0:02:35 --:--:--  0:02:35 1807k
  0  230M    0     0    0 1744k      0  1286k  0:03:03  0:00:01  0:03:02 1342k
  1  230M    0     0    1 2880k      0  1219k  0:03:13  0:00:02  0:03:11 1250k
  1  230M    0     0    1 4016k      0  1198k  0:03:17  0:00:03  0:03:14 1218k
  2  230M    0     0    2 5168k      0  1186k  0:03:19  0:00:04  0:03:15 1202k
  2  230M    0     0    2 6336k      0  1181k  0:03:19  0:00:05  0:03:14 1157k
  3  230M    0     0    3 7488k      0  1177k  0:03:20  0:00:06  0:03:14 1147k
  3  230M    0     0    3 8592k      0  1167k  0:03:22  0:00:07  0:03:15 1142k
  4  230M    0     0    4 9744k      0  1166k  0:03:22  0:00:08  0:03:14 1145k
  4  230M    0     0    4 10.6M      0  1163k  0:03:23  0:00:09  0:03:14 1142k
  5  230M    0     0    5 11.7M      0  1161k  0:03:23  0:00:10  0:03:13 1140k
  5  230M    0     0    5 12.8M      0  1158k  0:03:23  0:00:11  0:03:12 1133k
  6  230M    0     0    6 13.9M      0  1155k  0:03:24  0:00:12  0:03:12 1138k
  6  230M    0     0    6 15.0M      0  1155k  0:03:24  0:00:13  0:03:11 1138k
  7  230M    0     0    7 16.1M      0  1152k  0:03:25  0:00:14  0:03:11 1131k
  7  230M    0     0    7 17.2M      0  1152k  0:03:25  0:00:15  0:03:10 1132k
  7  230M    0     0    7 18.4M      0  1152k  0:03:24  0:00:16  0:03:08 1140k
```

I am using a simple Perl `system()` call to invoke CURL. Does anyone know what command line argument I can supply CURL to turn off the reporting of the upload progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason my version of CURL wasn't recognizing the -s or --silent which I know makes no sense. As @Friedo suggested I tried using backticks or the qx operator which also didn't get rid of unwanted upload progress reporting. Ultimately I went the very unelegant route of adding `>/dev/null 2>&1` to the end of the system call which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 10):

There are a few options here.

You can use the `-s` or `--silent` flag to silence all output. From the `curl` manpage:

> ```
>   -s/--silent
>          Silent  or  quiet  mode. Don’t show progress meter or error mes-
>          sages.  Makes Curl mute.
> ```

Or, rather than using something like `system` in your Perl script to run `curl`, you could use backticks or the `qx` operator to capture the output to a variable.

Or, you could open your `curl` process with a [pipe](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Using-open%28%29-for-IPC) to capture its STDOUT and look at it later.

Finally, you might want to explore replacing your system calls to `curl` with a native Perl library like [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm) or [Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize).

Comment: @ Friedo - Thanks for the all the options! I was looking for --silent but couldn't seem to find the right flag in the documentation.

Comment: You should remove the section about the "-o" option. That's for writing the downloaded data to a file, not the progress output. The question is asking about the progress output.

Comment: @Andrew, you're right; I misread the manpage. I'll edit the answer.