# Get result of cURL request fired by cron job

Tags: curl, cron

I've set up a cron job via my hosting account's cPanel. This basically calls an external URL every 30 minutes. I'm using cURL (as `wget` is disabled for me due to being on a shared server).

The command I fire is as follows:

```
curl http://www.example.com/filename.php
```

However, my email response comes back with the resultant HTML (which I want) but also prefixed with download information:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

 0     7    0     7    0     0     39      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    39
100   174    0   174    0     0    484      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   917
<html>
 ...
</html>
```

What parameter can I use to suppress the stuff above `<html>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-s` or `--silent`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699383/how-can-i-keep-curl-output-out-of-mail-from-my-cronjob).