# How can I quiet all the extra text when using curl within a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

Here's an example ip proxy checker shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read IP
do
    CURL=$(curl -x http://$IP -L http://icanhazip.com)
    echo "$CURL"
done < ip.txt
```

But instead of a simple result like:

```
0.0.0.0
1.1.1.1
```

I get:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
0.0.0.0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
1.1.1.1
```

How can I quiet the extra stuff?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I keep curl output out of mail from my cronjob?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699383/how-can-i-keep-curl-output-out-of-mail-from-my-cronjob)

Answer (score 28):

`-s/--silent`

Silent mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages. Makes Curl mute.
If this option is used twice, the second will again disable mute.

```
CURL=$(curl -s -x http://$IP -L http://icanhazip.com)
```

Comment: I have lived with this annoyance for a miilion years! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Often you want explicit error messages, but want to mute the progress meter alone instead.  You can use the `--no-progress-meter` flag:

```bash
CURL=$(curl --no-progress-meter -x http://$IP -L http://icanhazip.com)
```