# How can I filter elements from JSON

Tags: json, bash

It's my first day working with JSON.
For Example, how can I filter the `Title` and `IsExploitable` out of this script?

```
{
  "Title": "hello world",
  "ManualId": ten,
  "IsExploitable": false,
  "IsTicketAssigned": false
}
```

The final result should display the `Title: Hello World` and the Answer of `IsExploitable` which in this case is false.

I want to do this in bash.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking a question. This is not a code-writing-service! Please show what you tried, including related error messages or why the result is not what you expect. Please do not spam tags, include only the relevant tags in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `jq`:

```
$ jq '{Title, IsExploitable}' file
```

Output:

```
{
  "Title": "hello world",
  "IsExploitable": false
}
```

Comment: Can I combine this with a curl command?

Comment: Sure, if your output is pure json.

Comment: yes it is but how can I combine it I tried:

Comment: curl -X POST ........  | jq '{Title, IsExploitable}' file

Comment: Lose the `file` from the end and feed `jq` from stdin, smth like  `curl -X POST ... | jq '{Title, IsExploitable}' ` To make sure it is json: `curl ... > file` and then `jq '.' file` to see if there are errors.

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 37233  100 37233    0     0   109k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  109k
{
  "Title": null,
  "IsExploitable": null
}

Comment: this is the output when I try it with curl -X POST ... | jq '{Title, IsExploitable}'

Comment: Maybe this?: [How can I quiet all the extra text when using curl within a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853406/how-can-i-quiet-all-the-extra-text-when-using-curl-within-a-shell-script)

Comment: curl -X POST .... | jq '.Items[] | select( .IsExploitable == false ) | .Title, .IsExploitable' :tried it now with Items and select that works but it is written in one long line. Can I subdivide it?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You should post a new question and attach proper input (the output of `curl`), current output and the expectd output. Unfortunately these are impossible to handle in the comments.

Comment: I'm sorry. Because of the downvotes I got I only can ask my next question after 3 days. I know that it's hard to understand but I can't explain it better sorry :/